# The unit sphere with the $L^2$ norm in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is weakly closed in $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be an open, bounded set. I want to show that the unit sphere in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ with the $L^2$ norm, the set $S = \{u \in H_0^1(\Omega) : \int_\Omega u^2 = 1\}$, is weakly closed in $H_0^1(\Omega)$. This is a claim in an article I am reading. What I thought was the following:

Let $(u_n) \subset S$ be a sequence (weakly) converging to $u \in H_0^1 (\Omega)$. We must show that $u \in S$. Note that
\begin{align*}
\left| \int_\Omega u^2 \ dx - 1 \right| & = \left| \int_\Omega u^2 \ dx - \int_\Omega u_n u_n \ dx \right| \\
& = \left| \int_\Omega u^2 \ dx - \int_\Omega u u_n \ dx + \int_\Omega u u_n \ dx - \int_\Omega u_n u_n \ dx\right| \\
& \leq \left| \int_\Omega u^2 \ dx - \int_\Omega u u_n \ dx\right| + \left| \int_\Omega u u_n \ dx - \int_\Omega u_n u_n \ dx \right| .
\end{align*}
Now, consider the following functionals:
$$
f_1(u_n) = \int_\Omega u u_n \ dx, \qquad f_2(u_n) = \int_\Omega u_j u_n \ dx,
$$
with $u_j \in (u_n)$. By weak convergence, we have that 
$$
f_1(u_n) \to f_1(u), \qquad f_2(u_n) \to f_2(u).
$$
Then, given $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
\left| \int_\Omega u^2 \ dx - \int_\Omega u u_n \ dx \right| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$

Now, my intuition says that I can also say there is an $n$ such that 
$$
\left| \int_\Omega u u_n \ dx - \int_\Omega u_n u_n \ dx \right| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
Is this true? If so, why? If not, what is the correct way of proving the claim?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But it isn't even a subset of $H^1_0(\Omega)$. Also $M$ is not defined in your question.

Comment: I really did mess things up with notation. I apologize. I have edited the question and I believe now it makes sense. Would you mind taking another look.

Comment: If you utilize that $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded into $L^{2}(\Omega)$, you immediately obtain $\int_\Omega u^2 =1$. I recon this compact embedding lies behind the claim of the author (of the paper you mention).

Comment: In your proof you defined your functionals $f_1, f_2$ only for the sequence $u_n$, which is a little bit strange. Moreover, what you essentially try to show is that $\lim_n \langle u_n, u_n \rangle = \langle u, u \rangle$, but what you are doing by introducing $f_2$ is just hiding not justifying the difficulty with that.